# link_to tag in ruby on rails do not change the url in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Rails 5 with ruby 2.4
I have few statements written on the view page with the `link_to` tag when I click on the `link_to` tag the it redirect me to the next page but don the change the URL this is very strange for me here is my view page.

```
<div class="container">
  <%= render "shared/breadcrumb" %>
  <%= render "shared/back_button" %>
  <h2>Cader</h2>
  <div id="data_conversion_request">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <% if @job.nil? %>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= link_to 'Check out job', cader_available_job_path, class: '', title: 'check in an available job', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= link_to 'Check in a job', cader_check_in_job_path(:job_id => @job.id), class: 'btn btn-link', title: 'checkin job', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= link_to 'Release a job', cader_release_job_path(:job_id => @job.id), class: 'btn btn-link', title: 'release job', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <!--            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>-->
            <%= button_tag 'Download files', class: "btn btn-link", onclick: "job_files(#{@job.id})", data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#files'} %>
            <%#= link_to 'Download files', cader_downloads_path(:job_id => @check_cader[0].job_id), class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <%= button_tag 'History', class: "btn btn-link", onclick: "history(#{@job.id})", data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#history'} %>
            <%#= link_to 'History', cader_history_path(:job_id => @check_cader[0].job_id),class: '', title: 'Job History', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <div> System Tools</div>
      <ul>
        <!--        <li class="list-group-item">-->
        <%#= link_to 'Customer profile', 'javascript:void(0)', class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        <!--        </li>-->
        <!--        <li class="list-group-item">-->
        <%#= link_to 'Messages', 'javascript:void(0)', class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        <!--        </li>-->
        <!--        <li class="list-group-item">-->
        <%#= link_to 'Queue Status', 'javascript:void(0)', class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        <!--        </li>-->
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <%= link_to 'Job folder', cader_job_folder_path, class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        </li>
        <!--        <li class="list-group-item">-->
        <%#= link_to 'Reset timer', 'javascript:void(0)', class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        <!--        </li>-->
        <!--        <li class="list-group-item">-->
        <%#= link_to 'Recent Jobs', 'javascript:void(0)', class: '', title: '', data: {toggle: 'tooltip'} %>
        <!--        </li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="checklist_data_conversion" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="files" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="history" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    <% unless @job.nil? %>

    function history(id) {
        // console.log('Reached');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= cader_history_path(:job_id => @job.id) %>",
            data: {"id": id},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#history').html(data);
                // console.log('success');
            },
        });
    }

    function job_files(id) {
        // console.log('Reached');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<%= cader_downloads_path(:job_id => @job.id) %>",
            data: {"id": id},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#files').html(data);
                // console.log('success');
            },
        });
    }

    <% end %>

</script>
```

But the same `link_to` tag is working fine for rest of the pages in the application, please correct when is  written incorrect inside the page or is there any other way to write the `link_to` tag.

Comment: Are you using all these versions of rails ? Please remove all unwanted tags. Thanks

Comment: using rials 5.2.1

Comment: All your link_to tags on that view are doing the same behavior?

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo yes, after rendering this page